Lazy loading in spring core with component scan
Let’s say I have a bean A with @ Lazy and @Component(“A”) annotations defined. However my configuration class has @Componentscan(basePackages=“…..”) where lazyInit param is not mentioned(false apparently if not provided). Will the bean A be lazily loaded still or do I need to add lazyInit=true to componentscan for bean A to be lazily loaded. This is for Spring core application not spring boot
Expectation: we do not need to lazyInit value but without that beans will be lazily loaded

You do not need to add the lazyInit parameter inside the ComponentScan if your beans are annotated with Lazy. They will still be lazily loaded.
However, if the bean definitions are not explicitly annotated, you could use the lazyInit parameter inside ComponentScan to specify which bean packages to be lazily loaded.
So, no. You don't need to explicitly specify both of them. One should be enough.

To enable lazy initialization for a bean, you can choose from the following approaches:

On Individual Beans:
Add the @Lazy annotation to classes annotated with @Component or to methods annotated with @Bean.
This ensures that the bean is only created when it is first accessed.
On a @Configuration Class:
Apply the @Lazy annotation to a @Configuration class. This indicates that all @Bean methods within that configuration class should be lazily initialized.
Using @ComponentScan:
Set the lazyInit property to true in the @ComponentScan annotation @ComponentScan(lazyInit = true).
By default, lazyInit is set to false. If you want to revert to eager initialization, simply remove the lazyInit attribute.

Important Note:

Using @ComponentScan(lazyInit = true) will configure all scanned beans for lazy initialization. Be mindful of this when applying it globally.

Finally, I’d like to quote the following from the Spring documentation:



when a lazy-initialized bean is a dependency of a singleton bean that
is not lazy-initialized, the ApplicationContext creates the
lazy-initialized bean at startup, because it must satisfy the
singleton’s dependencies. The lazy-initialized bean is injected into a
singleton bean elsewhere that is not lazy-initialized.

